# Wrapping text in a <span> element via html.replace jquery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding text dynamically into a `<p></p>` element based on values of an array.

```
//if there's more than one of the same value in an array 'scores'
if (scores.filter(item => item == scores_max).length > 1) {
  similar = [];
  document.getElementById('num_cond').textContent += ' So does';

  //then create an array 'similar' with those values

  for (var i = scores.length - 1; i > max_index; i--) {
    if (scores[i] == scores_max) {
      similar.push(premierleagueteams[i].name)
    }
  };

  //loop through values of that array and add them as text into the element

  for (var i = similar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementById('num_cond').textContent += ' ' + similar[i];
  };
```

I then want to wrap those values in a `<span></span>` element so I'm using this:

```
for (var i = similar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

 $("#num_cond").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(similar[i], '<span class="team-color">' + similar[i] + '</span>');
  });
};
```

But it's not working, the text is added in fine, but for some reason this final loop isn't wrapping the elements in a span.

Edit: I should have specified, but when I type that last 'for' loop:

```
for (var i = similar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

 $("#num_cond").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(similar[i], '<span class="team-color">' + similar[i] + '</span>');
  });
};
```

into the console directly it works fine, but for some reason just running the program doesn't insert the span element.

HTML running the program:

```
<p id="num_cond">Everton meets 5 of your conditions. So does Leicester City.</p>
```

HTML after typing the for loop into the console:

```
<p id="num_cond">Everton meets 5 of your conditions. So does <span class="team-color">Leicester City</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the replace, you can instead use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to:

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

I've made an example on how to use it, you can adapt it to your code (since I don't know how your HTML is structured)

```js
 $("#num_cond").wrap('<span class="team-color"></span>' );
```

```css
.team-color {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="num_cond">text</p>
```

**UPDATE (to fit the OP requirements)**

Ok, so `.html()` returns the html content inside the element you're selecting with jquery. So when you modify the function you're only modifying what the `.html()` method returns. Not the content inside the element you're selecting.

With that being said, to modify the content inside of the element you selected with jquery, you need to place the content you want inside of the `.html` parenthesis like `$('#divId').html("my new content inside the div")`

[.html() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

So I made an example of what you need to place inside your `for` so it modifies the html content. Note that `$&` places the matched substring (similar[i] in this case).

[.replace() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

```js
var similar = ['Leicester City'];

for (var i = 0; i < similar.length; i++) {
  $("#num_cond").html($("#num_cond").html().replace(similar[i], '<span class="team-color"> $& </span>'));
}
```

```css
.team-color {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="num_cond">Everton meets 5 of your conditions. So does Leicester City.</p>
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap just a certain word/phrase within the num_cond id, not the entire element

Comment: Ok, please provide an example of your currently displayed HTML and what you expect so I can adapt my answer to your requirements

Comment: ok, I've edited my original post. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not embed the `span` tags when you are iterating over `similar` array.
Also cache your selector instead of querying the `DOM` for every iteration.

```
var $elem = document.getElementById('num_cond');
for (var i = similar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   elem.textContent += ' <span class="team-color">' + similar[i] + '</span>';        
};`
```

**or**

```
var $elem = document.getElementById('num_cond');
for (var i = similar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   elem.textContent += ` <span class="team-color">${similar[i]}</span>`;        
 };`
```

Comment: this didn't work. It's treating '<span>' just as a string, not an HTML element. elem.innerHTML didn't work either

Comment: Use `elem.innerHTML` instead of `elem.textContent`